# Join table by date only exclude seconds minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to join on two tables based on date value.

`TableA` got the `datetime` with seconds, minutes included like `2001-04-30 16:59:00.000`

`TableB` got the `datetime` without seconds, minutes included like `2001-04-30 00:00:00.000`

I want to join by date only

```
select * from dbo.TableA  m
LEFT JOIN TableB z ON z.DocId=m.DocId
AND CHARGE_DATE=z.DocDate
```

not giving proper result

Comment: It looks like you're excluding hours there too.  Do you want hours?

Comment: Agreed with @Khan. If TableB has no time, then say without time. And consider converting that column to DATE so that someone can't put time in there by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're 100% certain that TableB always has *no time*:

```
AND m.CHARGE_DATE >= z.DocDate
AND m.CHARGE_DATE <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, z.DocDate)
```

Or

```
AND CONVERT(DATE, m.CHARGE_DATE) = z.DocDate
```

You may want to flip these around depending on the usefulness of indexes on either of these columns.